# How do you upload a gzip package to PyPI on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

On Windows, I have uploaded a package using the following command:

`python setup.py sdist bdist_wininst upload`

However, due to my using Python on Windows, it uploads a zip file instead of a gzip file. How can I make it send a gzip along with it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with zip, though.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - But what about *nix users?

Comment: We have zip tools as well. In fact, many Unix users prefer to upload .zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [specify the formats](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html) of the compressed source files:

```
python setup.py sdist --formats=gztar,zip
```

Answer (score 1):

```
python setup.py sdist --formats=zip,gztar bdist_winist upload
```

Refer to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it has has the important `upload` command at the end.  Also note that the order of the arguments is significant, you can't put `--formats` at the end.